# Derivation of the Cartan Field equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, variational-calculus

Please help me understand how, in [this introduction to spacetime and fields](http://arxiv.org/abs/0911.0334), the Einstein Cartan equation:
$$C^k_{\hspace{2mm} [ji]}-\delta_{[i}^{k}C^l_{\hspace{2mm} j]l}=\frac{\kappa}{2}s_{ij}^{\hspace{2mm}k}, $$
when the starting variation to the Field equation with respect to the contortion tensor ($C$ being the contortion tensor, $s$ being the spin tensor) is derived to be

$$\frac{-1}{\kappa c}\int (C^{kj}_{\hspace{2mm} i}-C^{lj}_{\hspace{2mm} l}\delta_i^k) \sqrt{-\mathfrak{g}}\delta C^i_{\hspace{2mm}jk}\delta \Omega  \hspace{3mm} + \frac{1}{2c}\int s_j^{\hspace{2mm} ik}\sqrt{-\mathfrak{g}}\delta C^j_{\hspace{2mm}ik}\delta\Omega=0,$$

which leads directly to the expression
$$C^{kj}_{\hspace{2mm} i}-C^{lj}_{\hspace{2mm} l}\delta_i^k = \frac{\kappa}{2}s_i^{\hspace{2mm}jk}. $$

Is there some form of symmetrisation that can reduce this equation into the familiar form above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the spin tensor is skew-symmetric in its lower indices,
$$
s_{ij}{}^k=-s_{ji}{}^k
$$

Therefore, we have $s_{ij}{}^k=s_{[ij]}{}^k$. From this, its easy to see that
$$
A_{ij}{}^k=s_{ij}{}^k \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad A_{[ij]}{}^k=s_{ij}{}^k
$$
as required.

Comment: Awesome and simple - why I couldn't see this :) Thanks